# React-Select: Getting multiple onChange values from dropdown

Tags: reactjs, select, react-select

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
    { value: 'all', label: 'all' },
    { value: 'destroyed', label: 'Destroyed' },
    { value: 'damaged', label: 'Damaged' },
    { value: 'physicalDamage', label: 'PhysicalDamage' }
  ]


class SearchFilters extends React.Component {

    _onChange = (e, options) => {
        const onChangeData = {
          value: e.value,
          name: e.label,
          result: options.find(item => item.value === e.value)
        };
        console.log(onChangeData.value);
        return onChangeData;
      };

    render(){
        return(
            <div> 
              <Select
                options={options}
                onChange={e => this._onChange(e, options)}
                isMulti={true}
            />
          </div>
        )
    }
}
export default SearchFilters
```

From the above code if isMulti is false in select, I'm able to print the value of the selected option in console, but if I change it to true, I get the value as undefined.
I need help in fixing this. Thanks in advance.

Ouput: [image]

Comment: what you want, both cases works as expected, what is your expected output?

Comment: when isMulti={false} it prints output "destroyed" "damaged" etc..

when isMulti={true} it prints output as undefined.

I need onChange to work when I select MultipleOptions.

Comment: check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-select-custom-tag-edit-5t5t4n?file=index.js

Comment: I have added the outputImage that I'm getting when I select MulitpleOptions.

Comment: create demo in stackblitz to reproduce an issue